# Is there a Maven plug-in that can build a zip file for the primary JAR plus all dependent jars?

Tags: maven, zip

A newbie Maven question...

I have a Java JAR that holds junit tests.   I want to distribute this to run on another PC.  Is there a maven plugin that can build a zip file that includes the primary project jar plus all dependent jars?

TIA

Comment: Why do you like to put that jar which contains the unit test to run on other PC?

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Assembly Plugin can do what you need. See a tutorial [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/).